# What does this sentence in the motivation of having views in database mean?

Tags: database, view

I was wondering what the following sentence (particularly the highlighted parts) about the motivation of having views for databases means:

> if we did so, and the
> underlying data in the relations instructor, course, or section **changes**, the stored
> query results **would then no longer match** the result of reexecuting the query on
> the relations.

It comes from *Database System Concepts* (Silberschatz):

> **4.2 Views**
>
> It is not desirable for all users to see the entire logical model.
> Security considerations may require that certain data be hidden from
> users. Consider a clerk who needs to know an instructor’s ID, name and
> department name, but does not have authorization to see the
> instructor’s salary amount. This person should see a relation
> described in SQL, by:
>
> ```
> select ID, name, dept name
> from instructor;
> ```
>
> Aside from security concerns, we may wish to create a personalized
> collection of relations that is better matched to a certain user’s
> intuition than is the logical model. We may want to have a list of all
> course sections offered by the Physics department in the Fall 2009
> semester, with the building and room number of each section. The
> relation that we would create for obtaining such a list is:
>
> ```
> select course.course id, sec id, building, room number
> from course, section
> where course.course id = section.course id
> and course.dept name = ’Physics’
> and section.semester = ’Fall’
> and section.year = ’2009’;
> ```
>
> It is possible to compute and store the results of the above queries
> and then make the stored relations available to users. However, **if
> we did so, and the underlying data in the relations instructor,
> course, or section changes, the stored query results would then no
> longer match the result of reexecuting the query on the relations.**
> In general, it is a bad idea to compute and store query results such
> as those in the above examples (although there are some exceptions,
> which we study later).
>
> Instead, SQL allows a “virtual relation” to be deﬁned by a query, and
> the relation conceptually contains the result of the query. The
> virtual relation is not precomputed and stored, but instead is
> computed by executing the query when- ever the virtual relation is
> used. Any such relation that is not part of the logical model, but is
> made visible to a user as a virtual relation, is called a view. It is
> possible to support a large number of views on top of any given set of
> actual relations.

Comment: It basically means if the base table's schema changes it can invalidate any view that references it; trying to use the view would then raise an error. Some RDBMS eg SQL Server provide a mechanism to prevent this such as *schemabinding*.

Comment: why does saving the result into a new table change the underlying tables?

Answer (score 1):

It's stating that using a view to precompute and store a result does not guarantee the stored result will remain current as when the data in the table changes (added, updated, removed, etc).

So, if I execute and store the result of

```
select course.course_id, sec_id, building, room number
from course, section
where course.course_id = section.course_id
and course.dept name = ’Physics’
and section.semester = ’Fall’
and section.year = ’2009’;
```

and the `course` identified by `course_id` is deleted, the stored result is not going to be updated to reflect the new information because it is static and would need to be purged and recomputed regularly.

Using the virtual relation mechanism mentioned means that, when the record is deleted, the virtual relationship is triggered and updates the view is updated automatically.